# ReactChartJs Not Rendering

Tags: react-chartjs

I am new to react and am trying to get react-chartjs to work. I have the following code below, and I could not get anything to display. Doing npm run webpack went smoothly. Please help.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var Chart = require('chart.js');
var LineChart = require('react-chartjs').Line;

var myChart = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data: [{
                x: -10,
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: 0,
                y: 10
            }, {
                x: 10,
                y: 5
            }]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            }]
        }
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
<LineChart data={myChart.data} options={myChart.options}/>, 
 document.getElementById('app'));
```

Cheers
-- Pete

Comment: So what exactly happens? Do you see any errors in the browser console? Do you see just blank screen?

Comment: I am using Firefox. the console has this error message:
TypeError: root is undefined.

Comment: I got a blank screen and the firefox console says TypeError: root is undefined. Need help.